# 2 different scroll view on same window & scroll @different speed

Tags: ios, scrollview

How can i put 2 different scroll view on same window and scroll them at different speed while dragging . one such implementation i recently seen and most of you too might have seen is on the new Yahoo weather app. though there are very good other implementations on few other lesser known apps.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollview on top should have a delegate that knows about both scrollviews.  Inside that delegate you should implement the method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [bottomScrollView setContentOffset:(CGPoint) animated:(BOOL)]
}
```

Then you will have to calculate how slowly you would like to scroll the second scrollview.  Set the CGpoint based of a fraction of the top scrollview's content offset.